# Is it possible to reverse javascript code with symbolic tools

Tags: z3, symbolic-math

Look at this very basic javascript code:

```
function check(a,b,c)
{
    if (a[0]==a[1] &&  a[1]=='A' && a[2]=='C' && a.length==3)
    {
        console.log('Good !');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('Wrong !');
    }
}
```

It is easy to see the good value for 'a' parameter is 'AAC'.
Let's imagine a more complex javascript code.

What i want to do is to ask a tool to automatically resolve this kind of function.
I want to say: give me the a, b and c value that runs "Good !" Line code.

I know angr for binaries. But i am looking for a tool which works with javascript code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it myself, but a quick google suggests this: https://github.com/ExpoSEJS/ExpoSE

I'm not sure if it does everything you need, but being open-source, it might be a good place to start. Would be great if you try it out and write up your experiences!

Comment: I have looked at this project but it does not answer to my problem